# Extract substring with Regex on Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to extract a substring with Regex,

Here is my script:

```
import re
_text = "sdiskpart(device='D:\\', mountpoint='D:\\', fstype='FAT32', opts='rw,fixed')"
print(re.findall("device=(\\'.*\\')", _text))
```

I'm trying to get the value of device, in this string it's "D:\"

as u can see I tried "device=(\'.*\')" with REgex and it returned:

> ["'D:\', mountpoint='D:\', fstype='FAT32', opts='rw,fixed'"]

I'm not professional on REgex, How can I force it to take D:\ and print it out ?

Comment: >>> print(re.findall("device=(\\'[A-Z]:\\\\')", _text))
["'D:\\'"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use non-eager regexp

```
import re

print( re.findall("device='(.*?)'", _text))
```

notice that the .*? means non-eager so it will take the least chars until the next ' ...

Comment: what is the difference in performance compared to using `([^'])` (character class of inverse-quote, i.e. all characters but quote) ?

Comment: @njzk2 - running *timeit* resulted in that ".*?" is a bit slower. both does not require backtracking though so I guess they are somewhat in the same order of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

REFER https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

```
>>> print(re.findall("device=(\\'[A-Z]:\\\\')", _text))
["'D:\\'"]
```

You might have to replace * with [A-Z]. I think the drive letter are in caps always else use[A-Za-z]

Comment: what if there is no :\\\\ after [A-Z]?